# How to add the leaflet maps based on the no of elements

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, grid, ng-class

I want to add the leaflet maps on the page and the condition is..

If it is one it has to place with entire width with bootstrap grid columns, if it has two it has to place with in the row with same col widths (say col-6),and it is three means it has to place two maps in one row and one map in second row with entire width,

if it is five means two maps in one row two maps in second row and one map in third row with entire widh
*(note :the no of elements coming is dynamically from the backend)*

**.component.ts**

```
  
      for ( var j =0;j<this.sensorsarray.length;j++){

    var v= "map"+i+"";
    var  div=document.createElement("div");
    div.id = v;
      div.style="height:380px;";
                  console.log(v);
                
                  document.getElementById('mapper').appendChild(div);


// some code 
}
```

**.component.html**

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
      
     <div class="col-6" [ngClass]="{ 'col-12' : array.length %2 ==1 }">
        <div id="mapper"  style="height: 385px;border: 1px solid gray;"></div>  
   
        </div>
       
        
  </div>
```

Can any one help me for the above.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will solve your issue:

in .ts file your array is defined :

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

in html

```
    <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div *ngFor="let item of array; let i=index;" 
        [ngClass]="i===(array.length-1) && (array.length % 2!==0) ? 'col-12' : 'col-6'">
        <div id="mapper"style="height: 385px;border: 1px solid gray;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

For your updated question, I think this can be the solution :

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.sensorsarray.length; i++) {
      var v = "map" + i + "";
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = v;
      document.getElementById("mapper").appendChild(div);
      var map = document.getElementById("map" + i);
      map.style.height = "380px;";
      if (
        i === this.sensorsarray.length - 1 &&
        this.sensorsarray.length % 2 !== 0
      ) {
        map.classList.add("col-12");
      } else {
        map.classList.add("col-6");
      }
      // some code
    }

<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="w-100">
        <div id="mapper" style="height: 385px;border: 1px solid gray;" class="row"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anjs, but id mapper is an array of maps coming dynamically.I have added more code please check it

Comment: So, on which div you want to add col-6 or col-12 classes? mapper one or its parent

Comment: I want to add the classes for the parent one based on that only mapper has to place in the width

Comment: Can you add complete code here with proper issue that you are facing?

Comment: Basically what I need is based on the sensorsarray  elements(even or odd)  it has to show in the classses that what I mentioned above

Comment: I have updated the code,and based on the sensors array elements the rows has to place with in the rows number of maps has to place based on even or odd values of sensors array

Comment: So, there is a parent div with class row and inside that you have one mapper div and inside mapper you want even odd logic?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anjs, it is working but I need the rows also for ex..if the map is one it has to add one row  with col-12 width, if it is two means it has to add two columns of width col-6 within the one row ,if it has 3 means it has to add two columns within one row an done column with  col-12 width within the second row.. and so on.Can you please edit the above code.

Comment: Stackblitz link for your requirement https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-egvvxo?file=src/app/app.component.ts